# Multi-part question/answer/theorem

Tags: itemize

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: multi-part theorem]

Currently, I'm using `\item`, like this

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\phantom\\
\begin{itemize}
    \item bla bla bla.
    \item foo foo foo.
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I have to use `\phantom\\` to get the first bullet down, otherwise it would be on the same line with Theorem. This is ugly, and I think it's not the optimal way to get what I want. Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

With `enumitem` and `etoolbox`, you can set parameters for all theorem lists in the preamble::

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{\setlist{before=\leavevmode, nosep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}

\begin{itemize}
    \item bla bla bla.
    \item foo foo foo.
    \item fiddle dee dee! 
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]